# Overlaying SVG graphics - contradicting JavaScript files (Plotly / Distill.pub)

Tags: javascript, svg, plotly, plotly.js

I wanted to prepare a plot for a publication on https://distill.pub/guide/ using Plotly.js.

Everything works as expected until I add the script that deals with the layout on Distill (https://distill.pub/template.v1.js), then all the graphs are displayed incorrectly:

was: 
[correct - SVGs overlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLSU.png)

now is: 
[wrong - SVGs below each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJHQf.png)

I inspected the page in the browser and found that Plotly generates two SVGs (`<svg class="main-svg">`) that should be overlayed. The SVGs seem to remain the same if I add the Distill script but now are not displayed on top of each other (overlayed) anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix this or a workaround for this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the html code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://distill.pub/template.v1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var trace1 = {
      x: [2, 8],
      y: [0.25, 6],
      text: ['filled triangle', 'Cubic Bezier Curves'],
      mode: 'text'
    };

    var layout = {
      title: 'Basic Arbitrary SVG Paths',
      xaxis: {
        range: [0, 9],
        zeroline: false
      },
      yaxis: {
        range: [0, 11],
        showgrid: false
      },
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      shapes: [

        //Cubic Bezier Curves
        {
          type: 'path',
          path: 'M 1,4 C 2,8 6,4 8,8',
          line: {
            color: 'rgb(207, 114, 255)'
          }
        },

        //Filled Triangle
        {
          type: 'path',
          path: 'M 1 1 L 1 3 L 4 1 Z',
          fillcolor: 'rgba(44, 160, 101, 0.5)',
          line: {
            color: 'rgb(44, 160, 101)'
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    function start() {
        Plotly.newPlot("graph", data, layout);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
  <div id="graph"></div>
    </body>
```

I can reproduce this behavior of displaying the SVGs below each other if I create a html page that doesn't contain any Plotly functions but only the two SVG paths (as created by Plotly - copied from the browser) and then either

- add the Distill template.v1.js script or
- remove the plotly-latest.min.js script

So basically something in the plotly script makes the SVGs overlay as intended (but I don't know what and where) and it seems that something in the Distill script undoes it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- deactivating this out breaks it-->
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script> 

        <!--activating this breaks it, too-->
        <!--<script src="https://distill.pub/template.v1.js"></script>-->

    </head>

<body>
  <div id="graph" class="js-plotly-plot">
      <div class="plot-container plotly">
      <div class="svg-container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 500px;">

          <svg class="main-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
          <g class="cartesianlayer">


              <!--text annotations-->
              <g class="plot" transform="translate(80, 100)" clip-path="url(#clipb71614xyplot)"><g class="scatterlayer mlayer"><g class="trace scatter trace365c60" style="stroke-miterlimit: 2; opacity: 1;"><g class="points">
                  <g class="textpoint" transform="translate(0,3)"><text x="75.56" y="312.73" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="filled triangle" data-math="N" text-anchor="middle">filled triangle</text></g>
                  <g class="textpoint" transform="translate(0,3)"><text x="302.22" y="145.45" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="Cubic Bezier Curves" data-math="N" text-anchor="middle">Cubic Bezier Curves</text></g>
                  </g></g></g></g>
              <!-- numbers x-axis -->
              <g class="xaxislayer-above"><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="0" data-math="N" transform="translate(80,0)">0</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="2" data-math="N" transform="translate(155.56,0)">2</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="4" data-math="N" transform="translate(231.11,0)">4</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="6" data-math="N" transform="translate(306.66999999999996,0)">6</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="8" data-math="N" transform="translate(382.22,0)">8</text></g></g>
              <!--numbers y-axis-->
              <g class="yaxislayer-above"><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="0" data-math="N" transform="translate(0,420)">0</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="2" data-math="N" transform="translate(0,361.82)">2</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="4" data-math="N" transform="translate(0,303.64)">4</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="6" data-math="N" transform="translate(0,245.45)">6</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="8" data-math="N" transform="translate(0,187.26999999999998)">8</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" data-unformatted="10" data-math="N" transform="translate(0,129.09)">10</text></g></g>
             </g>
          </svg>



          <svg class="main-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500">

              <!-- paths/shapes -->
              <g class="layer-above">
                  <g class="shapelayer">
                      <path data-index="0" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 117.78,303.64 C 155.56,187.26999999999998 306.66999999999996,303.64 382.22,187.26999999999998" style="opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(207, 114, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 0; stroke-width: 2px;" clip-path="url(#clipb71614xy)"></path>
                      <path data-index="1" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 117.78 390.91 L 117.78 332.73 L 231.11 390.91 Z" style="opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(44, 160, 101); stroke-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(44, 160, 101); fill-opacity: 0.5; stroke-width: 2px;" clip-path="url(#clipb71614xy)">
                      </path>
                  </g>
              </g>

              <!-- title -->
              <g class="infolayer"><g class="g-gtitle"><text class="gtitle" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; fill: rgb(68, 68, 68); opacity: 1; font-weight: normal; white-space: pre;" x="250" y="50" text-anchor="middle" data-unformatted="Basic Arbitrary SVG Paths" data-math="N">Basic Arbitrary SVG Paths</text></g><g class="g-xtitle"></g>
              <g class="g-ytitle"></g>
              </g>

          </svg>        
</div>
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I also asked this question on community.plot.ly but have not received any answers there yet. I will update here if I find a solution there.